I get this ⨯ RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with NextJS, Supabase, and React Query
Getting this error
✓ Compiled in 1316ms (829 modules)
 ○ Compiling /lobby/[id] ...
 ✓ Compiled /lobby/[id] in 2s (1728 modules)
 ⨯ next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (1469:16) @ logRecoverableError
 ⨯ RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "2761827113"
  1467 |         request.pendingChunks++;
  1468 |         prevKeyPath = request.nextChunkId++;
> 1469 |         task = logRecoverableError(request, key, task);
       |                ^
  1470 |         emitErrorChunk(request, prevKeyPath, task, key);
  1471 |         return parent
  1472 |           ? "$L" + prevKeyPath.toString(16)

With this following code:
useFetch.ts
    import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/client";
    import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query";

    const supabase = createClient();

    export const useFetchTeamLogin = () => {
       return useMutation({
          mutationFn: async (teamName: string) => {
      try {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
          .from("teams")
          .select("teamToken")
          .eq("teamName", teamName)
          .single();

        if (error) throw new Error(error.message);
        return data;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("Mutation error:", err);
        throw err;
      }
    },
  });
};

login.tsx
"use client";


import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTrigger,
  DialogContent,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogDescription,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog";
import { useFetchTeamLogin } from "@/hooks/useFetch";

export default function Login() {
  const [teamName, setTeamName] = useState<string>("");
  const { mutate: fetchTeamLogin, error, isError, isPending } = useFetchTeamLogin();
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!teamName.trim()) {
      console.error("Team name cannot be empty.");
      return;
    }

    fetchTeamLogin(teamName.toLowerCase(), {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        if (data?.teamToken) {
          router.push(`/lobby/${data.teamToken}`);
        } else {
          console.error("Team token is undefined.");
        }
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.error("Error during login:", error.message);
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <Dialog>
        <DialogTrigger asChild>
          <Button className="w-80 font-bold p-5 text-white bg-orange-500 hover:bg-orange-700 cursor-pointer transition-colors">
            Join the Hack!
          </Button>
        </DialogTrigger>
        <DialogContent className="border-none bg-[#1e1e1e] w-[350px] rounded-md">
          <DialogHeader>
            <DialogTitle className="text-2xl text-orange-600 font-pixelify text-left">
              {isError ? <p className="text-red-500">{error?.message}</p> : "Login"}
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogDescription className="text-md text-gray-600 text-left">
              Please enter your correct information
            </DialogDescription>
          </DialogHeader>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Team Name"
              className="w-full text-gray-400 p-3 bg-transparent border border-gray-300 rounded-md mb-2"
              value={teamName}
              onChange={(e) => setTeamName(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
            <p className="text-[10px] text-gray-300 text-right mb-3">
              Input in lowercase with no whitespace character
            </p>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              disabled={isPending}
              size="lg"
              className="w-full bg-orange-500 text-white hover:bg-orange-600 transition-colors"
            >
              {isPending ? "Authenticating..." : "Login"}
            </Button>
          </form>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}

lobby.tsx
export default function Lobby() {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
      <h1 className="text-lg font-bold mb-4">
        Welcome to the Lobby
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

What I'm trying to do is once the team name inputted by the user, and validated that it is existing in my database, it will redirect to the "/lobby/[teamToken]" route.
But, I always get that error and I don't know what would be the problem. Thank you!
